# When to Know If Vectors are Implemented Vertically Or Horizontally Within a Matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

This is my first time asking a question on stack exchange so please bear with me.

Sometimes I see vectors in matrices in row form i.e. for simultaneous equations but when checking for linear independence the vectors are inserted as columns. I know that this is because ***aV<sub>1</sub> + aV<sub>2</sub> + aV<sub>3</sub> = 0*** where a is a scalar multiple of the vectors so I am adding the x<sub>1</sub> from each vector, the x<sub>2</sub> accordingly etc... But how do I know if given a co-efficient matrix, whether they are implemented in a row or column format or in other words if they are vertical or horizontal within the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the challenges of linear algebra, so you're asking a good question. Of course, given a question you want to solve, you can always set it up so that either way works, but I agree that it is more natural one way than the other.

You already pointed out that when you think of a system of equations $A\vec x = \vec b$, we treat $\vec x$ and $\vec b$ as column vectors and the coefficients of each equation become the row vectors of $A$. On the other hand, the columns of $A$ still have a meaning: The vectors $\vec b$ for which this system of equations is consistent (i.e., has a solution) are precisely the *column space* (span of the columns) of $A$.

Indeed, solving for $\vec x$ in $A\vec x=\vec b$ tells you the coefficients of the respective column vectors that gives you the linear combination $\vec b$: If $\vec a_j$ are the columns of $A$, then the equation $A\vec x=\vec b$ can be rewritten as $\sum x_j\vec a_j = \vec b$. This then leads naturally to the question of linear dependence/independence to which you already alluded.

Suppose I hand you vectors $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_m\in \Bbb R^n$ and ask you to find the orthogonal complement of the subspace they span; that is, I want you to find all vectors $\vec x\in\Bbb R^n$ so that $\vec v_i\cdot\vec x=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$. Well, then, if you put the $\vec v_i$ in as the *rows* of a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, you're looking for the *nullspace* of $A$ (i.e., all solutions of $A\vec x=\vec 0$). But you could put them in as the columns of an $n\times m$ matrix and find the so-called *left nullspace* (i.e., all solutions of $\vec x{}^\top\!\!A = \vec 0{}
^\top$).

Here's one for you. Suppose I give you two planes in $\Bbb R^3$, one spanned by $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$, and the other spanned by $(1,0,1)$ and $(2,-1,1)$. Can you find all the vectors that are in both planes?

Comment: Hmmm well there is an approach where I can make an equation both planes using the normal for both planes. Then I can calculate the intersection of both planes and solve all of the possibilities for which ****ax + by + cz + d = 0****. However this is deriving from my question which is knowing when to implement vectors in a matrix vertically or horizontally, or when can I tell if the co-efficient matrix has its vectors implemented vertically or horizontally. The examples that you gave me were very helpful so do I just need to know how the vectors are formatted based on experiencing the question?